# Why does my sinningia have yellow spots?

Tags: diagnosis, sinningia

*Click below images to enlarge...*

[image: sinningia]
[image: sinningia]

This is probably Sinningia Ozark Coral Freckles. I put it in a aquarium with artificial light on from 8:00am to 0:00am. The distance to light is about 20cm.

The young leaves were fine until they grew bigger and I found yellow spots within their leaves. I also spotted 2 tiny red dot things ( tiny, like dust ) on the leaves. I touched one of the red dots with a tool and it didn't move; I picked it out. I don't think they are red mites.

Any clues as to what is causing the yellowing?

Comment: Maybe try these resources for some ideas: [Gloxinia](http://www.ext.nodak.edu/extnews/hortiscope/flowers/gloxinia.htm) & [Gloxinia (Sinningia)](http://www.ct.gov/caes/cwp/view.asp?a=2823&q=377716) & [Bacterial Leaf Diseases of Foliage Plants](http://www.extension.umn.edu/distribution/horticulture/dg1170.html)

Comment: I am no native speaker, do you know there are any formal names for what we called "small sinningia" and "super small sinningia"? I already know the name of big sinningia is Gloxinia.

Comment: Do you mean this? [Grouping of Sinningia Species](http://www.burwur.net/sinns/sinntax.htm)

Comment: I found out that. I mean mini sinningia and micro mini sinningia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consulted some friends in internet. They said those are watermark caused by too much humidity. I think it is quite reasonable. Maybe I will move it out of the aquarium later.

Comment: I believe your friends could well be right, the following comes via the first link [I posted above](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/why-does-my-sinningia-have-yellow-spots#comment-3018), [Gloxinia](http://www.ext.nodak.edu/extnews/hortiscope/flowers/gloxinia.htm) -- *Water from the base, not the top and use only tepid water. Any water getting on the leaves will cause spot diseases.*

Comment: And this link: [Bacterial Leaf Diseases of Foliage Plants](http://www.extension.umn.edu/distribution/horticulture/dg1170.htmls) -- talks about the importance of not wetting the leaves & high humidity, both of which can cause problems resembling what you're currently seeing...